# Fail to transafer Ether to child contract from parent contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, factory

I created a contract factory (parent contract) for creating a child contract. In the parent contract, there is a function to transfer the balance of the parent contract to the child contract, by entering the child contract address. I found that the transfer will be successful when the receive function is plain (no other action in the receive function). When I add other actions like changing the state variable, then the transaction will fail and show the error:

`transact to ContractFactory.pay errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.`

Here is the contract code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

contract ContractFactory {
    address[] contractsAddress;
    mapping(address => Contract) private contracts;
    
    function createContract(uint price) public {
        Contract newContract = new Contract(msg.sender, price);
        contractsAddress.push(address(newContract));
        contracts[address(newContract)] = newContract;
    }
    
    receive() external payable{
    }
    
    function pay(address payable contractAddress) public payable{
        contractAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    
    function getAllContractsAddress() view public returns(address[] memory) {
        return contractsAddress;
    }
}

contract Contract {
    enum Status {Unavailable, Available}
    Status public contractStatus;
    
    address payable public contractOwner;
    address payable public buyer;
    
    uint public price;
    
    event Occupy(address _occupant);
    
    constructor(address payable _contractOwner, uint _price) {
        contractOwner = _contractOwner;
        price = _price;
        contractStatus = Status.Available;
    }
    
    modifier onlyWhenAvailable {
        require(contractStatus == Status.Available);
        _;
    }
    
    modifier notOwner {
        require(msg.sender != contractOwner);
        _;
    }
    
    modifier payEnoughAmount {
        uint priceInEther = price * 1 ether;
        require(msg.value >= priceInEther);
        _;
    }
    
    receive() external payable onlyWhenAvailable notOwner payEnoughAmount {
        contractStatus = Status.Unavailable;
        buyer = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

`contractAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);`

To:

`contractAddress.call{value: address(this).balance}("");`

Why? Because when using methods `transfer()` and `send()` the called contract can use only 2300 gas which apparently is not enough to update state. And this is why your function succeed when the `receive` method of contract `Contract` was empty and not updating the state of the called contract.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add a little background for others who find this answer. The "gas stipend" (2,300) rule was added following the DAO incident. It provides retroactive re-entrance protection for naive contracts (including legacy deployments) that do not observe the "checks, effects, interactions" pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the addition, it is totally valid.